# Side boxplot comparisons of labels

Tags: r, boxplot

Here's my dataset `dput_data`.

```
dput_data <- structure(list(Label = c(" Flight", " Flight", " Flight", " Flight", 
" Flight", " Ground Control", " Ground Control", " Ground Control", 
" Ground Control", " Ground Control", " Ground Control"), `210885` = c(2.46726120893655, 
-0.174636990542105, -0.463404328357544, 2.3996395908089, -0.150507030748742, 
5.64497005685753, 3.36669883823842, 0.0291245138878325, -0.0720040453347311, 
1.23592496897254, -0.435680321628551), `110647` = c(-0.183451995597915, 
-0.232101174582698, -0.418549509261665, 3.12474114229781, -0.963627404680163, 
-0.295591624345765, 3.74110668642539, -0.307620588051106, 4.95070981495709, 
-0.248418667713625, 0.556071497195402), `120996` = c(2.958740197185, 
-0.658764097795927, -0.720985892268865, -0.605140415143121, -0.614856607147667, 
2.84170000321244, 2.4703391289031, 1.89042697528755, 1.38117056072924, 
2.66548725562505, -0.775258323014181)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(35L, 
36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L))
```

Which looks like this

```
             Label      210885     110647     120996
35          Flight  2.46726121 -0.1834520  2.9587402
36          Flight -0.17463699 -0.2321012 -0.6587641
37          Flight -0.46340433 -0.4185495 -0.7209859
38          Flight  2.39963959  3.1247411 -0.6051404
39          Flight -0.15050703 -0.9636274 -0.6148566
44  Ground Control  5.64497006 -0.2955916  2.8417000
45  Ground Control  3.36669884  3.7411067  2.4703391
46  Ground Control  0.02912451 -0.3076206  1.8904270
47  Ground Control -0.07200405  4.9507098  1.3811706
48  Ground Control  1.23592497 -0.2484187  2.6654873
49  Ground Control -0.43568032  0.5560715 -0.7752583
```

Currently I've tried:

```
library(reshape2)
dput_dat <- melt(dput_data, id.vars = 'Label', measure.vars = c('210885', '110647', '120996'))
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dput_dat) + geom_boxplot(aes(y=value, color=variable)) + facet_grid(.~`Label`)
```

This gives me two sets of boxplot, one with Flight and another of Ground Control.

[image]
But I would prefer to have the boxplot of `210885` `Flight` and `Ground Control` right next to each other so I can make a direct side-by-side comparison (with differing colours for the Flight and Ground Control). Same applies to the `110647` and `120996`. All of which in a graph.

I'm a bit at a loss to how to procede.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about use Label as x variable and your variable for facetting as follow:

```r
library(tidyverse)

data %>% pivot_longer(-Label, names_to = "type", values_to = "value") %>%
  arrange(desc(type)) %>%
  mutate(type = factor(type, levels = unique(type))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Label, y = value, color = Label))+
  geom_boxplot()+
  facet_wrap(~type)
```

[image]

Is it what you are looking for ?

Comment: oh I was hoping to have the difference colours for Flight and Ground Control instead. But this is still quite acceptable. Do you know how I could order the graphs (left to right - 210885, 110647, 120996)?

Comment: You're welcome ;). I edited my answer to show you how to set the color for Label and set the desired order for the facetting. Let me know if it is ok for you.

Comment: Oh thanks! I noticed that you've used descending for the order, is it possible to specify the order myself?

Comment: Sorry, I did not notied that the order was not descending. You can remove the arrange and change the `mutate` function by `mutate(type = factor(type, levels =  c("210885", "110647", "120996")))` that should work